# JQuery Mobile - Setting attributes programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I use Jquery Mobile 1.0.1 inside a Drupal 7 Theme.
I want to customize the Back Button but cannot change the property of the data value.

This is the script that is inserted before Jquery Mobile loads:

```
var $jqm = jQuery.noConflict();
    $jqm(document).bind("pageinit", function() {
    console.log("mobileinit"); // Not loaded
$jqm(".ui-btn-left").jqmData("icon", "arrow-l"); // Thus, not set
})


$jqm(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  console.log("mobileinit"); // This happens though

  $jqm.mobile.ns = '';
  $jqm.mobile.autoInitializePage = 1;
  $jqm.mobile.subPageUrlKey = 'ui-page';
  $jqm.mobile.activePageClass = 'ui-page-active';
  $jqm.mobile.activeBtnClass = 'ui-btn-active';
  $jqm.mobile.ajaxEnabled = 1;
  $jqm.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = 1;
  $jqm.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';
  $jqm.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'pop';
  $jqm.mobile.minScrollBack = 150;
  $jqm.mobile.loadingMessage = 'indlæser';
  $jqm.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage = 'Error';
  $jqm.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = 1;
  $jqm.mobile.pushStateEnabled = 1;
  $jqm.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = 0;    

});
```

The mark up after Jquery Mobile has wrapped looks like

```
<a class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-a"       data-ajax="false" data-icon="home" data-rel="home" title="Forsiden" href="/" data-theme="a"> <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"> <span class="ui-btn-text"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home ui-icon-shadow"></span> </span> </a>
```

Comment: can you post html markup?

Comment: <a class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all       ui-shadow ui-btn-up-a" data-ajax="false" data-icon="home" data-rel="home" title="Forsiden" href="/" data-theme="a">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
<span class="ui-btn-text">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home ui-icon-shadow"></span>
</span>
</a>

Comment: Changes can be done after jqm is loaded and on either `pageinit` or `pagebeforeshow` events. Add the markup to your question body :)

Comment: I don't understand - I already did that in the code above, and that clearly doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to change the icon of the Home button. Changing `data-icon` won't change the icon since class `ui-icon-home` is already added into the second `span` of the button. So instead of changing the `data-icon`, remove class `ui-icon-home` add then class `ui-icon-arrow-l`, do the below.

**Button**

```
<a data-role="button" data-ajax="false" data-icon="home" data-rel="home" title="Forsiden" href="/" data-theme="a">Home</a>
```

**JQM**

```
$jqm(document).on("pageinit", function() {
 $jqm("[data-role='button'].ui-btn-left").buttonMarkup({icon: "arrow-l"});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hm, I get TypeError: $jqm(...).on is not a function. I have tried changed to  $jqm(...).bind but that does not help.

I cannot modify the markup - this is generated by drupal (simple A-tag).